# Wordpress menu disappear when using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a PHP snippet that i've included in my wordpress page. When I add this code to the snippet the snippet keeps working fine, but my WordPress menu (the top bar) disappears. How can I fix this? If I remove this code, everything is working fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      type: "iframe",
    });
  });   
</script>
```

Comment: 1. Check if you have any error in console.  2. Right click to see if there's any css applied on the menu which could hide it.

Comment: Firstly check the console for errors. Secondly, upgrade your version of jQuery. 1.4 is almost 10 years out of date. Also note that I re-tagged the question as neither PHP or WordPress are relevant to the problem.